# Int has no attribute remove

Tags: python, attributes, int

I want to remove a random element in an array , so i did like this:

```
word = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
for i in range(len(word)-1):
    word[i].remove(randint(0,9))
print word
```

However, there is an error "Int has no attribute 'remove' 
Help me please

Comment: Please format your question properly.

Comment: word[i] gives you a element from word, ie, a integer in this case, since int has no attribute remove u cant call remove. U need to call word.remove ,  See https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: You're picking an individual number from the list, and then trying to remove an element from that number as if it were a list. `1` isn't a list, neither is `2`, etc; but you're trying to remove a number from each of those numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Well `word[i]` is an int and there is no function `remove` for int.
Try:

```
from random import randint    
word = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
word.remove(randint(0,9))
print word
```

Answer (score 0):

Here `word[i]` will be the element in word changing in loop

If you are trying to remove element by `item`, use

```
word.remove("item") #remove 1st occurence of element.
```

If you are trying to remove element by `index`, use

```
del word[index]
```

Answer (score 0):

`word[i]` is an `int` which doesn't have a `remove` method (well, you already know that from the error message).

In order to pick a random element from a list you can use `random.choice`. Then use the `remove` method of `list` to remove it. Keep in mind that if the same element is found more than once in the list then only the first occurrence will be removed from the list.

```
from random import choice

li = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
random_element= choice(li)
li.remove(random_element)
print(li)
# [1, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I just could not understand your question.
Delete a random item from the list using the following code:

```
from random import randint
word = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
min = 0
max = len(word)
word.remove(randint(min,max))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like your aim is to delete all but one (random) element from the list? So why not simply pick a random element from the list?

```
import random

word = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
word = random.sample(word, 1)
```